# How to convert values in rows into column (header and values format) using oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a table in the form(result set from a select query )

| rec_no | f_id | f_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1502 | text1 |
| 1 | 1503 | text2 |
| 2 | 1502 | text3 |
| 2 | 1503 | text4 |
| 2 | 1508 | text5 |
| 1 | 1509 | text6 |
| 1 | 1508 | text7 |
| 2 | 1509 | text8 |

and i need to convert this table in the below format

| recno | 1502 | 1503 | 1508 | 1509 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text1 | text2 | text7 | text6 |
| 2 | text3 | text4 | text5 | text8 |

the values inside ***f_id*** may vary but number of ***recno*** for reach ***f_id*** would be same. How to format the first formatted data into the second form using oracle script?

Comment: Don't pivot it in Oracle (as SQL, not just Oracle, requires statements to have a known set of columns and yours are not known). Instead, pivot it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `group by` and `DECODE` function to pivot the rows into columns :

```
SELECT
    rec_no,
    MAX(DECODE(f_id, 1502, f_value)) "1502",
    MAX(DECODE(f_id, 1503, f_value)) "1503",
    MAX(DECODE(f_id, 1508, f_value)) "1508",
    MAX(DECODE(f_id, 1509, f_value)) "1509"
FROM mytable
GROUP BY rec_no
ORDER BY rec_no;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/3w7dk-_T)

Comment: Thanks ,but like i said ,this f_id values are dynamic ,i cant hard code those values

Comment: Question is closed somehow, so i am posting query here :select * from (select f_id,recno,f_value from #temp)pivot(max(f_value) for f_id in (<i generated this through dynamic sql>)